# Top N people with fastest times across all laps

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
      Name1 Name2 Name3 NameN
Lap1  1:20  1:30  1:19  1:40
Lap2  1:40  1:40  1:20  1:40
Lap3  1:30  1:19  1:22  1:20
LapN  1:19  1:21  1:20  1:19
```

I need to pull some statistics from a similar data set.
For example person with the most fastest laps, person with most 2nd fastest laps, etc.
I can't use a helper column.
Output In the format "NameN - count"

In this case the person with fastest laps would be "Name3 - 2 laps", 2nd fastest laps "Name1 - 2 laps" etc.

I tried adapting this formula I found from Excel but I can't make it work.

```
=LET(range,B2:E4,
nrows,ROWS(range),
ncols,COLUMNS(range),
ncells,COUNT(range),
races,INT(SEQUENCE(ncells,1,0)/ncols+1),
names,MOD(SEQUENCE(ncells,1,0),4)+1,
headers,B1:E1,
winners,SEQUENCE(nrows,1,1,ncols),
times,INDEX(range,races,names),
INDEX(headers,(MODE(INDEX(SORTBY(CHOOSE({1,2,3},races,names,times),races,1,times,1),winners,2)))))
```

Comment: Will every name have a score for every lap, as shown in your posted example data? Or might some names be left blank for some laps? And will there only ever be *one* winner per lap, as shown in your posted example data? Or might there be ties in any given lap? As you can see, there are other potential factors here. I suggest you post a link to a sample spreadsheet illustrating all realistic possibilities per the questions above.

Comment: yep, some names might have not done laps. they'll be blank or '-'.  
realistically there will only ever be one winner, in real dataset the times are way different but if it was "easy" to implement ties I would use that just to be safe.

Comment: You also have the realistic case that there would be multiple returns for top performer per place. For instance, even in your short data set, if each person came in 1st for one of the four laps, you'd have *four* names that all performed equally with 1 1st-place win. I want to be clear here, for the sake of your expectations, that my questions are not necessarily a promise that I will solve this. It *can* be solved. But it would be complex, given the number of factors and cases—more complex than is likely to be developed for you on a free volunteer-run forum.

Comment: At a minimum, as I suggested, you should post a link to a sample spreadsheet that illustrates *all realistic possibilities*, e.g., ties, names blank per lap or with a "-" (and which of those you use matters), etc. But do realize that, even given such a link, this requires a customized, time-intensive, expert-level solution; and most volunteers will feel that goes beyond the scope of this forum to provide.

Comment: If the solution by player0 works as expected, please close this post by marking that reply post as "Best Answer." If it does not, please respond today to my above comments (including sharing a link to a sample spreadsheet). I've kept this post up in a separate browser window for two days now; but volunteers shouldn't be working more on a post than the person who posted it. I'm not meaning to be unkind here, just realistic.

Answer (score 0):

first we find the fastest time per lap:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A2:A10)&"♦"&B2:E10), "♦"), 
 "select min(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label min(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

next, we substitute times for names:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B2:E10<>"")*(B2:E10=F2:F10), B1:E1, ))
```

[image]

and now we can count top players:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(G2:J10), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

all in one:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(IFERROR(IF((B2:E10<>"")*(B2:E10=
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A2:A10)&"♦"&B2:E10), "♦"), 
 "select min(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label min(Col2)''")), B1:E1, ))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

and if you want you can add `limit` like this:

[image]

Comment: it gives a formula analysis error. I've got the same data as in the OP.
But I have to say I don't quite understand your output? I don't believe it's doing what I need?

Comment: @user23868267 answer updated

Comment: thank you!  
I still must be doing something wrong.
Even this part of the formula does not work and throws "array value could not be found" error.

`ROW(A2:A10)&"♦"&B2:E10`

more specifically, when I add the 'B2:E10' part. I can't even use it separately.

Comment: @user23868267 to use it separately you need to wrap it into `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A2:A10)&"♦"&B2:E10)`